# How can I read out text on my computer?

Tags: software-recommendation, text-to-speech

By text I refer to different formats such as:

- A website opened in my web browser
- An article stored in my [Pocket](https://getpocket.com/)
- An email opened in Gmail through my web browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Scripts on custom shortcuts

We can use terminal commands assigned to a keyboard shortcut to read parts of the screen.

To assign a script to keyboard short cut open *System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts* to create a new shortcut with <kbd>+</kbd>.

[image]

Give a sensible **name** to the shortcut (e.g. `ReadScreen`). Enter the **full path** to one of below scripts in the **command** line. After we had applied the new shortcut we need to press the desired keyboard shortcut, e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd>, making sure it does not yet exist.

Choose any of below scripts (or both on different keys) depending on your needs.

---

#### Case reading selected text:

Save the following script as e.g. `ReadClip` to a sensible place and give it executable permission.

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

xclip -o | espeak
```

On pressing the predefined key the default speech synthesizer [**espeak**](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=espeak) [image: Install espeak] will read all selected text, or in case no text was selected the content of the clipboard (if text) by using [**xclip**](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=xclip) [image: Install xclip].

Of course we can adapt the script to use any other speech synthesizer (e.g. **spd-say**).

---

#### Case reading text including text on images

Save the following script as e.g. `ReadShot` to a sensible place and give it executable permission.

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

gnome-screenshot -a --file=tmp.png &&
tesseract tmp.png stdout | espeak
```

On pressing the predefined key we can select an area of our screen using the default screenshot tool. The resulting image will be processed by the OCR software [**tesseract-ocr**](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=tesseract-ocr) [image: Install tesseract-ocr] and then will be read out using [**espeak**](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=espeak) [image: Install espeak].

The results are not quite as good as from processing text files but they still are remarkably good, and we can use this for **all that is displayed on the screen** including images. In case we don't want to keep the temporary image `tmp.png` we can add a `rm tmp.png` to the script.

For both, **[tesseract](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/tesseract)**, and for **[espeak](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/espeak)** there are many options including support for languages other than English.

Answer (score 0):

Look for a screen reader. There aren't that many for Linux, one is [Orca](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Orca)  developed by the gnome team. There is a [list on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_screen_readers) that you can browse.